# python pandas: add missing date after groupby and calculate the quantity

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe like below

```
   stock__stock__FINCODE  quantity   price transcation_type       month
0                 100112    1000.0  2000.0              buy  2022-06-01
1                 100112     500.0  2000.0              buy  2022-06-01
2                 100112    1200.0  3000.0             sell  2022-08-01
3                 100112     100.0  3000.0             sell  2022-08-01
4                 100112     200.0  3000.0             sell  2022-08-01
5                 100325     100.0  1500.0              buy  2022-06-01
```

I did groupby with `stock__stock__FINCODE`, `transcation_type` and `month`, and made sum of `quantity`. The code and result is as below

```
cols = ['stock__stock__FINCODE', 'month', 'transcation_type']
df2 = df.groupby(cols)[['quantity']].sum().add_suffix('_sum')
```

```
                                                   quantity_sum
stock__stock__FINCODE month      transcation_type              
100112                2022-06-01 buy                     1500.0
                      2022-08-01 sell                    1500.0
100325                2022-06-01 buy                      100.0
```

but I want the result on each month and if a sell happens in same month then need to substract with the buy.
If any month is not available then add that month and make the quantity same as previous month.

the result should be some thing like below.

```
                                             
stock__stock__FINCODE 2022-06-01 2022-07-01 2022-08-01        
100112                1500       1500       0
100325                100        100        100
```

the date column is basically monthly quantity. It should start from the smallest date to till now.

can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Question is not very clear. Can you give an example calculation for one month. Like how you derive it using qty remaining qty and transaction type

Comment: I'm sorry i have update the cols list and i am only doing quantity sum for both sel and buy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.
You will need to create a daterange index

```
date_range_index = pd.date_range(start=df.month.min(),end=df.month.max(), freq='MS')
date_range_index_df = pd.DataFrame(index=date_range_index)
```

Unstack df2 to create 2 columns one for buy one for sell

```
cols = ['stock__stock__FINCODE', 'month', 'transcation_type']
df2 = df.groupby(cols)[['quantity']].sum().add_suffix('_sum')
df2_unstack = df2.unstack(level='transcation_type').reset_index()
df2_unstack.columns = df2_unstack.columns.map('_'.join)
df2_unstack = df2_unstack.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df2_unstack.month_)).fillna(0)
df2_unstack
```

Use pandas `reindex` to create a function and get the cumulative

```
#df2.sort_index()
def apply_on_each_stock(gdf: pd.DataFrame):
    gdf_up = gdf.reindex(date_range_index,fill_value=0).sort_index(level='month_')
    gdf_up['cumbuy'] = gdf_up['quantity_sum_buy'].cumsum()
    gdf_up['cumsell'] = gdf_up['quantity_sum_sell'].cumsum()
    gdf_up['qty_rem'] = gdf_up['cumbuy'] - gdf_up['cumsell']
    return(gdf_up)

df2_ops = df2_unstack.groupby(['stock__stock__FINCODE_']).apply(
    lambda row: apply_on_each_stock(row)
)
```

And then you reshape as you want

```
df2_ops['qty_rem'].unstack(level=1)


2022-06-01  2022-07-01  2022-08-01
stock__stock__FINCODE_          
100112  1500.0  1500.0  0.0
100325  100.0   100.0   100.0
```